# JS/Ajax - Change page with PHP in ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Ive got an ajax type script changing div content with data from a PHP file using xmlhttp:

```
function updatelog() {
request = 'messages.php?new='+first+'&time='+lastupdate+'&user='+user;
xmlhttp.open("GET", request ,false);
xmlhttp.send();
document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML=document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML+xmlhttp.responseText;
lastupdate = time();
first = 0;
document.getElementById("messages-window").scrollTop = document.getElementById("messages-window").scrollHeight;
}
```

I want to redirect the user using `header( 'Location: kick.php' );` but it only redirects the XML request, not the whole page.
how can i redirect the whole page and not just the request?

Comment: So `updatelog` calls `message.php` which redirects with PHP and you want it to redirect the calling page - i.e. the parent of `updatelog()`?

Comment: yep, the PHP will usually return HTML though, it only redirects when i call for it too, (thats all handled in messages.php)

Comment: do you actually get a response for this code? There is no 'onreadystatechange' method handler for the xmlhttp object.

Comment: One way to do it is: get a response and IF(CONDITION) redirect via JS Code (e.g. if(responseText =='redirect') window.location = 'kick.php';)

Comment: yeah i get a response why wouldn't i?

Comment: ok my mistake...it's not an Asynchronous request so you don't need the readystate handler.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript redirect

window.location = "kick.php"